# Paragraph aside image is starting from bottom-left and NOT top-left

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the paragraph -- I want the text to start from `top-left` but by default its starting from `bottom-left`. Is there any simple way to directly tell paragraph, to start text from "top-left" only. I don't know any such CSS or command. If somebody knows, pls help out.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
h1 {background:#000;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:10px;}
.content {padding:20px;}
.green-box {border:2px solid #9a9a9a;padding:10px;}
.green-box > * {display:inline-block;}
.green-box p {text-align:top-left;}
```

```html
<h1>Fighter Aircrafts</h1>

<div class="content">
  <div class="green-box">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
      <p> ...content... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: I want to tell/CSS paragraph and set its default text to be top-left. Also, not make any `makeshift arrangements` like doing [img float:left], etc.

Comment: vertical-align:top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before flexboxes something like that would be solved with the float attribute.Since flexboxes you could do something like that:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
h1 {background:#000;color:#fff;padding:5px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:10px;}
.content {padding:20px;display:block;position:relative;}
.green-box {border:2px solid #9a9a9a;padding:10px;display:flex;position:relative;}
```

```html
<h1>Fighter Aircrafts</h1>

<div class="content">
  <div class="green-box">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
      <p> ...content... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```